# Python OR operator and parenthesis

Tags: python

Example 1 - This works:

```
def thisorthat():
    var = 2

    if (var == 3 or var == 2):
        print "i see the second value"
    elif (var == 2 or var == 15):
        print "I don't see the second value"

thisorthat()
```

Example 2 - This does NOT work:

```
def thisorthat():
    var = 2

    if var == (3 or 2):
        print "i see the second value"
    elif var == (2 or 15):
        print "I don't see the second value"

thisorthat() # "I don't see the second value"
```

Is there a way to compare a variable to an "OR" operator without repeating the variable twice in each line?

Comment: You could try `if var in (2, 3, 15)`.

Comment: Why did 3 people upvote this? This is literally one of the most duplicate questions under the Python tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an equivalent way:

```
if var in [2, 3]:
    ...
elif var in [2, 15]:
    ...
```

and you are using `var` only once per condition.

**Notes:**

- This is not using `OR` directly.
- The `2` in the second condition doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of what you are doing wrong:

In Python, `or` doesn't always work like in English. It takes two arguments and sees if either of them has the boolean value `True` (returning the first one that does). All non-zero numbers have the boolean value `True`, so `var == (3 or 2)` is evaluated to `var == 3`, which as `var` is 2, evaluates to `False`. When you do `var == (2 or 15)`, you get `var == 2`, which is true, so the code below that `elif` statement is executed.

Like has been suggested, you should do `var in (3, 2)` instead.